# Pixel-Perfect collision for ignoring transparent areas of sprites

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've recently come across Pixel-Perfect collision between two sprites from this link: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/18522.

I'm just wondering if its possible to implement this using 1 sprite and CGPoint(touch). If this is, can anybody explain how to implement it that way? Thank you

Comment: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/fast-pixelperfect-collision-detection-cocos2d-code-1of2/