# Nodes collision testing - but not on bouding rectangles

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm looking for some simple and somehow efficient way to detect collisions of Nodes (not necessarily Sprites) while ignoring collisions of transparent parts of Nodes' images.
It is easy to implement bounding Rects collision... but it does not reflect the transparency.

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699400/pixel-perfect-collision-for-ignoring-transparent-areas-of-sprites) were published other approach named "Pixel-perfect"... ok, but I see it as inefficient and somehow complicated. In cases of full-hd and bigger displays...

I suppose it could be possible to yield some "non-transparent" masks of both sprites, get them only in intersect of their bounding rects and finally perform AND operation on those masks...

Please, did anybody see something similar? Or better? Can I yield transparent and non-transparent parts of image of node?

I also found [this](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/fast-pixelperfect-collision-detection-cocos2d-code-1of2/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928748/ignoring-transparent-areas-of-sprites-in-cocos2d) well. Not studied yet but now I'd like use cocos2d-js .... :)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Give quadtrees a try. The algorithm works by splitting nodes into 4 quadrants recursively into a list with likely collideables. There are plenty of resources about them.

I combined this with pixel perfect check. I'm afraid it's the only way to properly check images' collisions short of using the per pixel algorithm to create unique concave and convex shapes to represent the collision space and then using other algorithms (such as Minkowski portal refinement). However if you images change or are animated, your game can takr an equal performance hit.

Interestingly enough, pp intersection was used in games like pong, with much less processing power. Pp also gives the most accurate intersection as compared to other algorithns.

Comment: Thank you for prompt reaction. Aha, interesting. But I guess in pixel-perfect approach you still alloc too many big buffers and render sprites repeatedly to those buffers. Is it correct? And yeah, then you use pretty fast alg to search in the buffer.

Comment: I have this implemented in a game I designed. I asked the same exact question on gamedev.stackexchage. I'd reccomend using hash lists so you can delete duplicate x,y coordinates and check if list is bigger than 0 for pp intersection.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for your recommendations. I looked around and I found the Pixel-Perfect to be probably the most handy starting point. Thanks again.
Zbynek

Comment: Also as a tip for the future, you should start to think about how you will interpolate collisions. (An object's space every update interval is digital causing a 'skip'. The more speed an object has, the higher chance it has of skipping an intersection it should have triggered)

Answer (score 0):

You can use physics collisions. And set-up physics body to repeat not-transparent part of the node.